# To tokenize terminals or write them into parser grammar?

Tags: parsing, tokenize, verilog, yacc, lex

Take a look at this: http://www.verilog.com/VerilogBNF.html

UNARY_OPERATOR and BINARY_OPERATOR overlap as tokens. so does OUTPUT_SYMBOL and LEVEL_SYMBOL. I'm sure there are others.

My tokenizer (lex) does not have any context and does not know if it should return a UNARY_OPERATOR or a BINARY_OPERATOR.

I could write these tokens (UNARY_OPERATOR & BINARY_OPERATOR) into the parser (yacc) grammar if they aren't tokenized by a lex-rule.

The problem I have is with OUTPUT_SYMBOL and LEVEL_SYMBOL, I can't write parser-grammar for this because sometimes the will be matched as IDENTIFIERS by the tokenizer.

I hope I'm clear

Answer (score 3):

I just uploaded a Verilog grammar which works fine with [LRSTAR 9.1](http://lrstar.tech).  The grammar can be found in the download found here: [downloads](http://lrstar.tech/downloads.html).  It's written in a newer grammar style than the one you referenced above.

The binary operators should be specified in the parser grammar, not the lexer grammar.  I'm not sure what the problem is with OUTPUT_SYMBOL, because I have not analyzed that grammar with a parser generator to see what the conflict report says.

If OUTPUT_SYMBOL has the same look as IDENTIFIERs, there is a way to distinguish 
them from s by doing a lookup in a symbol table.  If the OUTPUT_SYMBOLs do not have to be put in the symbol table and the identifiers are declared previously, then a simple lookup will tell you whether you have an OUTPUT_SYMBOL or identifier.

If you specify in the grammar OUTPUT_SYMBOL : idenfitier and you get a conflict, then you can change the rule to: OUTPUT_SYMBOL : output_symbol, which can be the terminal returned by the symbol table lookup (if it is not found in the symbol table).

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Verilog, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that grammar - it's ancient, and will almost certainly be wrong.

You need to give an example of a specific problem. lex doesn't need any context for Verilog - return a token, and sort it out in yacc.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have is with OUTPUT_SYMBOL and LEVEL_SYMBOL, I can't
>   write parser-grammar for this because sometimes the will be matched as
>   IDENTIFIERS by the tokenizer.

Yes. A UDP table entry potentially contains identifiers and numbers. You'll need to a create a series of rules like this:

```
udp_seq_table_entry :
  udp_table_prefix+ COLON table_element COLON table_element SEMICOLON;

udp_table_prefix :
   table_element
 | edge_indicator;

edge_indicator :
  LPARAN table_element
  (
    table_element RPARAN // X?, ?X, 1b,... two tokens
  | RPARAN               // xB, xX, B1,... one token
  );

table_element :
  DECIMALNUMBER | IDENTIFIER | '-' | '?' | '*';
```

Then your tool will have to inspect the identifiers and numbers to ensure they only contain the correct characters after parsing.

I would not attempt to simply pass the Verilog EBNF to a parser generator. Some things like module_instantiation and udp_instantiation potentially cannot be distinguished until after design elaboration. I've never used it but Verilog-Perl has a Verilog(1364-2005) parser.